# Vlookup exact text on a cell text string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to lookup a specific text on a cell which has a text string on it. 
I'm using `VLOOKUP("*"&E2"*",$A$2:$B$16,2,0)` but it's not giving me the desired result.

Here's a screenshot of my sample sheet:

[image]

I'm looking up **Unique** with **Keywords** and reflect the corresponding **Clicks** on Column F. In the example, both *travel* and *accessories* in the **Unique** column should have **72 Clicks** based on column B.

This is the desired result however, *packing* and *cubes* are the only one's that should have **26 Clicks** based on the **Keywords** column. My formula included *pack* and *cube* to have **26 Clicks** even though they should just have 1 and 3 respectively.

Is there a way of making the Vlookup formula, or any function for that matter, lookup the specific text on the **Unique** column on the text strings in the **Keywords** column?

Comment: @pnuts, I think it's because the Vlookup function searched for it from top to bottom and disregarded duplicates on other cells once they found a match. Maybe that's another issue that needs to be addressed.

Comment: What I need help with at this time is to have the Vlookup function or any function for that matter to lookup the specific **Unique** keyword.

Comment: I see. But why is it giving *pack* and *cube* both 26 clicks when they should only have 1 and 3 respectively. Only *packing* and *cubes* should have 26 clicks based on the top to bottom rule of Vlookup. This is what I'm trying to figure out, to have the formula lookup the specific text not just part of it.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to lookup the values aside from this?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not being clear. Simply put, I just want to have the specific **Unique** keyword to lookup the corresponding clicks on the **Keyword** text strings. I.e. *Packing* should get 26 clicks and not *pack* since it's not the exact unique word which is *packing*.

Comment: @Pnuts, you're a GOD. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Pnuts, I've reviewed the formula and it only works if `A:A` has only 2 words in it but if it's more than that, it's not calculating. It's not calculating words in the middle. Is there a work around for this?